# Regular expression appending content only on certain inputs

Tags: java, regex

How can I append a string (here `Calc!`) to only certain words (here `B`(and followed by a number) e.g. `B1/B2....`) only when the word does not have another string attached to it before it  (here `Input!`). example
`B1 -> Calc!B1`

and `Input!B1 -> Input!B1` (here no change)

```
Input - "=B1+B4"
Output - "=Calc!B1+Calc!B4"


Input - "=DIVIDE(B2,Input!B1)"
Output - "=DIVIDE(Calc!B2,Input!B1)"
```

Comment: Can you reformat this so it's easier to read?

Comment: what is a problem here ?

Comment: Define special string.

Comment: I meant 'Input!' as I have mentioned in the question

Comment: I don't see *any* similarity between the first input and output. Can you explain it more simply?

Comment: Sorry, My bad, edited the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<![!])B[0-9]+", "Calc!$0");
```

The expression to match the input is constructed as follows:

```
(?<![!])B[0-9]+
 ^^^^^^ ^  ^  ^
    |   +--+--+--- Letter "B"
    |      +--+--- Followed by a digit
    |         +--- Repeated one or more times
    +------------- Unless preceded by an exclamation point
```

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/twYvWx)

Comment: Thanks! I really really need to understand how regex works. It just confounds me. Thanks for your help and effort to make it understand.

Comment: If you need help with regex, I highly recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

You can replace this match:

```
(?<!Input!)(?=B\d+)
```

with this replacement:

```
Calc!
```

More details:

`(?<!Input!)` matches a position that is not preceded by `Input!`.

`(?=B\d+)` matches a position that is followed by `B\d+`, or `B` and at least one digit.

Together, they match at the position where you want to insert `Calc!`.